# Examples of uniform lattices - reference

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Being interested in uniform lattices (that is, discrete co-compact subgroups) of connected Lie groups, I am searching for a literature with abundance of examples.

Comment: Did you ask the same exact question at Mathoverflow few days ago and got an answer?

Comment: Crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/415658/66883 (Ycor's comment there coincides with my recommendation).

Comment: One should not ask the same question simultaneously here and at MO in order to avoid duplication of efforts. If you do not get a satisfactory answer in one site, then wait for a week band ask at the other but leave notes about crossposting.

Comment: Alright, Moishe, I will keep your advice in mind and act accordingly in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Witte Morris' book *Introduction to Arithmetic Groups* (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063) is a good place to start; it has plenty of examples (and references to more sophisticated resources). Brown's lecture notes *Entropy, Lyapunov exponents, and rigidity of group actions* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09192) is also worth looking into; though it's more specialized to smooth ergodic theory.